# How can I view a localhost apache website from another computer on the same network?

Tags: raspberry-pi, apache2

I have a Raspberry Pi on my network on which I would like to host a website. I don't want to plug it to a monitor but still be able to work on the website.

So I access it via SSH from my main computer to edit the files etc... but I didn't find a way to view the website from my main computer.

I didn't wrote over the `000-default` website but created a new one so I see the default Apache page when I type in http://localhost.

I also tried using `ssh -X` but my main computer is a Mac and I have issues with making X11 work.

So my question is how can I preview from my Mac an Apache website that is not the default one, when the website is hosted on a Raspberry Pi on my network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two methods

- Setup a VNC connection

  Connect using ssh to RPi and prepare it for VNC using `sudo raspi-config`
  at `Interfacing options` enable VNC and at `Advanced options` set the resolution. Then use a VNC client on your MAC to connect to RPi

  Useful link: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/
- Using Local Forwarding

  `ssh -L 8080:intra.example.com:80 gw.example.com`

  This example opens a connection to the gw.example.com and forwards any connection to port 80 on the local machine to port 8080 on intra.example.com.

  Useful link: https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example